# HTML table with fixed col width broken when cell content is an input element

Tags: html, css

I have legacy code which I'm trying to improve step by step.

At some point I have a table with `table-layout: fixed`. And a colgroup element defining the size of each column.

The problem is that the column sizes are not correct when the cell's content is an input element.

You can check with this code snippet where the first column should be 20px.
http://jsfiddle.net/ppRgV/158/

What would be a good solution to not define a specific size on the input element?

Comment: The input bring default width, set this on your css - input{
  width: 100%;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

Just set the width to the first column's input element.

```css
.RowHeader {
  background-color: black;
}

.GroupCaption {
  background-color: #868981;
}

.RecordPlusCollapse {
  background-color: red;
}

.RowHeader input {
  width: 100%;
}

.Table {
  table-layout: fixed;
}
```

```html
<table id="Grid1_Table" class="Table">
  <colgroup>
    <col style="width:20px">
    <col style="width:20px">
    <col style="width:180px">
    <col style="width:200px">
  </colgroup>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="RowHeader">
        <div><input></div>
      </td>
      <td class="RecordPlusCollapse">
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
      </td>
      <td colspan="2" class="GroupCaption">Order ID: 0 - 1 Items</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

It works if you add the following CSS rule:

```
.RowHeader div {
    width:20px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n5obvd4s/1/